# Perfmon showing only average values

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, perfmon

I have a dataset of perfmon data for "\System\Context switches/sec" from a number of servers, I want to show the MAX, not the average. However, the perfmon tool will only show the averages.

I created the dataset by running perfmon with a data collector set on each of 15 Win2008 servers. I copied all the .blg files to my Win8.1 machine, then used 'relog' to combine those .blg files, and filter for only the "\System\Context Switches /sec" datapoint.

When plotting the resultant file, the Perfmon graphing program will only graph the averages, not the maximums, even after changing the "report and historgram data" radio button to 'maximum' under the "Properties/General" setup tab.

Suggestions?

Thanks,